# Update one field multiple times in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sql-update

Good day all.

I've done a script that copy a CSV in a database, then starts to import the data in the system. This is done by passing multtiple times over the whole "import" table, first to import categories, then to take products...and so on.
each time the script passes, it update a flag field called `importato`, when I copy the CSV it is 0, then I import categories, so i put it at 1, then 2, and so on. In this way I can keep track of what is going on.

If i encounter some error during the import, I set the `importato` field to 10, so at the end I have all the items that has got some errors. But I would like to keep track of past imports, so every time I write the CSV I update the `importato` to 11, then to 12 then 13 and finally I delete all the 13. This is done by a series of `update`:

```
if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM `importazione` WHERE importato = 13")){

        if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM `importazione` WHERE (importato = 4) OR (importato = 5) OR (importato = 6)")){  

            if(mysql_query("UPDATE importazione set importato = 13 where importato = 12")){

                if(mysql_query("UPDATE importazione set importato = 12 where importato = 11")){ 

                    mysql_query("UPDATE importazione set importato = 11 where importato = 10");
                }   
            }           
        }
    }
```

the problem is... the field is never updated, it stay at `10`... no error is thrown ...
could be a problem of buffering in someway? Or i'm committing some kind of error i don't get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that because the result of `mysql_query` if passed to an `if` statement that one of them is failing which means the other queries beneath it won't get run.  Check your user has the right permissions to be able to do a `DELETE FROM`.

Also the way you are doing it is very inefficent.  You could do what you are doing in 5 queries in 2

```
if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM `importazione` WHERE importato = 13 OR importato IN (4,5,6)") {
    mysql_query("UPDATE importazione SET importato = importato + 1 WHERE importato IN(12,11,10)");
}
```

Please note that `mysql_` functions are now deprecated so you should consider using an alternative

Comment: good point. the user has the rights to do this, but the thing about the IFs could be right, i'll try your code.